# How do I count regeneration spells against the Druid's daily and per-battle total?

Tags: 13th-age

The level progression chart for the Wild Healer Druid (*13 True Ways*, page 63) has both daily and per-battle uses for regeneration spells. Does this mean that a druid can cast the spell the per-battle amount in battle, and then expend daily uses whenever they please over the adventuring day? Or is the per-battle use a hard cap on usage per battle, leaving daily uses for use between combats?

For an example, I have two per-battle uses and one daily use of the spell on level 4. Can I use both of my per-battle uses and the daily use in a single combat encounter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can use all three uses of regeneration in a single fight

You're correct in thinking that the the two columns provide you two 'pools' of regeneration spells to cast. The per battle refreshes on a Quick Rest, while your per day pool only refreshes on a Full Heal Up.

You can see a similar approach to the Wild Healing spell in the Wild Healer adventurer feat, which gives your adept a pre-battle use of the spell.